# ColdFusion and PHP in same Flex application

Tags: php, apache-flex, coldfusion

I am working on a web application in Flex.

I have already used PHP as a "Flex Server", but now I need to add a mailing service and it seems that ColdFusion is the perfect tool for it.

I don't want to waste time and rewrite all the PHP services to ColdFusion, so I am wondering if it is possible to have PHP and ColdFusion in the same web app.

In the project properties for Flex Server I can only choose PHP or ColdFusion but not both.
Can I somehow manually connect to ColdFusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the project properties for Flex Server I can only choose PHP or
>   ColdFusion but not both. Can I somehow manually connect to ColdFusion?

The Flex Server option is really meaningless in Flash Builder.  I think it helps Flash Builder find the services-config file.  I always leave it blank or select none and manually specify the services config file as a compiler argument.

I assume you are using AMF / Flash Remoting; is that correct?  You can find the services-config file that is currently being compiled into your app and modify it to add a new destination for ColdFusion services.  You may want to combine your current services-config file with the one that comes with ColdFusion.

You should look for the CF Serivces-config file in a directory similar to this:

> C:\JavaServer\servers\CFInstanceName\cfusion.ear\cfusion.war\WEB-INF\flex

It'll be slightly different if you're using the standard edition of ColdFusion instead of the multi server edition.  I'm not sure where to find the PHP config file; but the two files should be very similar.

Of course, I assume that PHP can also send email relatively easily and I'm not sure the short-term gains of building this will outweigh the long term headaches of dealing with two technologies side by side.

Comment: thanks! after adding "-services "C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\WEB-INF\flex\services-config.xml" to additional compiler arguments everything runs smooth